# Searching through a nested multidimensional array for multiple values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I create an array:

```
nMap = [[[x,y, math.inf, True]for y in range(width)]for x in range(height)]
nMap = np.array(nMap)
```

I then take that array and set a value's distance to 0

```
nMap[0][0][2] = 0
```

After that I use a for loop to only run when all of the values in a array is set to false

```
while (np.all(nMap[:,:,3]) == False):
```

Then I create an array that returns the coordinates of all nodes which are not equal to false

```
tempNode = np.where(nMap[:,:,3] != False
```

Finally, I use this node to create a single point coordinate where the distance value is the smallest and the value is equal to False

```
minNode = np.where((nMap[:,:,2] == np.amin(nMap[tempNode[0][:][0],tempNode[0][:][1],2])))
```

Then I assign a cumulative distance to the neighbors of the point with the smallest distance and set the minNode coordinates to False in nMap. This program should loop around each time, but when I test the code, it sets minNode to 0,0 0,1 0,2... but when it reaches the end of the column it loops infinetly by setting minNode to 0,1. My question is if there is a way to find both the boolean value and the smallest distance for a point and be able to use those coordinates. Thank you in advance

Comment: It's better to give a **minimal** example otherwise the question would be hard to understand.

Comment: Stick with the `[:, :, 3]` style indexing through out.  `tempNode[0][:][0]` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: There's nothing `nested` about your array.  It is a 3d array of floats.